# Invalidate pointer values inside a QMap

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, memory-management, qmap

I'm having what seems to be a weird issue, but it could be a quirk of how QMap's work and I just don't understand it.  It's tough to summarize the problem, but I'll do my best.

I have a class `A`, with a `QMap<QString, someType*> mySomeTypeMap;`.  When I load a new file in my program, I want to delete all the contents of this `QMap` so I can repopulate it with new data.  I do that by doing the following:

```
foreach (QString key, mySomeTypeMap.keys())
{
    someType* toDelete = mySomeTypeMap.take(key);

    //Show me the original address of the pointer
    qDebug() << "toDelete: " << toDelete;

    delete toDelete;

    //Set the pointer to 0x0
    toDelete = NULL;
}
```

The `qDebug()` statement prints out the correct address of the value I want to delete, and when I look at `toDelete` in the debugger after it gets set to `NULL`, it says 0x0, which is what I want.

Then later, in a different class `B`, I have the following code...

```
void B::setSomeType(someType* blah)
{
    if (Blah != NULL)
    {
        //Calls a bunch of disconnect()'s
        disconnectAllSignals();

        Blah = blah;

        //Calls a bunch of connect()'s
        connectAllSignals();
    }
}
```

Now, what's really confusing is my program crashes when it gets to the `disconnectAllSignals();` line.  The reason being it's trying to call `disconnect()` on `Blah` which was deleted and should have been set to 0x0 when I set it to `NULL`.  However, if it was actually set to `NULL` it never would have entered that if-block to begin with.  In a debugger, I see that the address of `Blah` is exactly the same as what I get when I print out `qDebug() << "toDelete: " << toDelete;` right before setting `toDelete = NULL;`.

TLDR; I don't know how my program is getting the orignal address of a pointer back after I delete the pointer and set the same pointer to `NULL`.  Since the pointer isn't set to `NULL` later in the execution it leads to a crash.

Comment: First guess: You are not following the **Rule of Three** for `someType`. Show us the definition of `someTye`. Also, what does `mySomeTypeMap.take(key)` return a copy of the original element or pointer to element itself?

Comment: Well, the constructor and destructor are both empty...it's a very simple data class that doesn't contain any pointers that I would need to clean up.  I don't explicitly implement a copy constructor.  How would that cause a problem anyways?  And to answer your second question, http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qmap.html#take

Comment: `QMap::take(..)` removes the entry from the map, so what's the point nulling it afterwards?  It doesn't exist in the map and the copy goes out of scope immediately.

Comment: Where does `Blah` come from? `toDelete = mySomeTypeMap.take(key)` **removes** the item with index `key` from the map and stores it in `toDelete`. It's pointless to assign to `toDelete` (a local variable) after you've called `delete` on it. The problem must be elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Values in the map are stored by value even if in these case it means that the pointer (address which it points) is stored by value.
For example:

```
someType* toDelete1 = mySomeTypeMap.take(key);
someType* toDelete2 = mySomeTypeMap.take(key);
someType* toDelete3 = toDelete1;
toDelete1 = NULL;
```

toDelete2 & toDelete3 will still point to the original object

Instead of making the pointer null after delete you should either remove it from the map or set the value for that key to NULL.

Answer (score 2):

```
someType* toDelete = mySomeTypeMap.take(key);
```

This is a pointer variable created on stack and its value is set to the value that you keep in map. You dont need to set it to NULL, because it goes out of scope right away.

`take` function is removing pointer from the map, if you use it again with the same key it will return default-constructed value. Just after `delete` try to

```
mySomeTypeMap.insert(key, 0);
```

Comment: Ok, the "default-cunstructed value" for primitive types is set by Qt containers to 0, so you don't need the last line from my answer. The problem must be elsewhere.